# My first Android app's output does not show

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in Android and am trying to run the Hello World but when the Emulator shows up, only the Android image is shown. My output "Hello World" never shows up.

**`MainActivity.class`**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView text = new TextView(this);
        text.setText("Hello World, Android");
        setContentView(text);
       // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

When the Emulator pops up i can wait for 5-10mins but yet the output never shows up. I haven't change anything in any of the XML files. Am trying to test the "hello world" program.

I am using Eclipse.

### Edit

**`activity_main.xml`**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**`androidManifest.XML`**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Emulator should look like normal android phone after booting. You can try to speed-up boot in Eclipse: Run > Run Configurations > Target tab > Check "Disable boot animation" box

Comment: You will need to post your XML as @Sieryuu said above. Also be aware the emulator, on first boot, can be incredibly slow. On my last PC (dual core, 2 GB ram running XP) it took upwards of 15 minutes to get past the 'Android' logo when booting. That PC just did not want to boot it. Once it is open you can just rerun your code without closing and reloading the device. Have you tried running hello world on your physical device?

Comment: @RossC :: Thanks for your comments. I don't have physical device

Comment: @RossC :: AM also using Windows XP Pentium 4 with 0.99 GB RAM. Can that be the issue?

Comment: are you sure the text don't show up? is it because of your screen color is the same with your textview color? try `text.setTextColor(color.BLUE);`

Comment: @EddyFreeman I think the issue is in the code in this case. The answer from Martijn Van Mierloo should solve your problem, but just to be aware that the emulator can be incredibly slow on some computers. Try his answer and go get yourself a coffee while it boots up the emulator! I've seen a few people think it was entirely the code's fault but it was the 20 minute booting time. Let us know how you get on!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you add your `Activity` to the `AndroidManifest` file?

**Example**

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name=".YourActivity">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Update**

Change

```
setContentView(text)
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

This means you will use your predefined XML file as the layout for this `Activity`.

If you want to change the TextView inside your xml:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // find the TextView in the XML file defined by setContentView
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTextView);
    text.setText("Your text");
}
```

Do not forget to add the attribute `android:id="@+id/mTextView" to the TextView in your XML.

Comment: :: Please am just purely beginner so help me how to do it. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Open your project > Find the AndroidManifest.xml > Click on the tab below called AndroidManifest.xml > Check if your Activity is declared inside the application tags

Comment: :: I have edited my post and added the androidManifest XML file. I think the "MainActivity" is already included. Have aa look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You must edit the manifest.xml:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: what's different in this answer. And what you want to tell?.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to "improve" your MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  //The XML where the text view is
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TEXTVIEWID); // The id of the text view
        text.setText("Hello World, Android");

    }
}
```

Then the xml should be:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TEXTVIEWID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

For the basics you can just follow [this](http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.ch/2010/01/hello-world-your-first-android.html) tutorial!